# Jmeter - How to assign multiple dynamic values to a variables inside a loop

Tags: jmeter

I have loop like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    log.warn("opponentA: " + vars.get("ID1_" + i).split(" - ")[0]);
    log.warn("opponentB: " + vars.get("ID1_" + i).split(" - ")[1]);
}
```

which produces values like:

```
2021-06-08 11:01:51,649 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: France
2021-06-08 11:01:51,649 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Bulgaria
2021-06-08 11:01:51,649 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Poland
2021-06-08 11:01:51,649 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Iceland
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Senegal
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Cape Verde
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Czech Republic
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Albania
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Hungary
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Republic of Ireland
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Morocco
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Ghana
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Kosovo (FIFA APPR.) U21
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Andorra U21
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Sweden U21
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Luxembourg U21
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Faroe Islands U21
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Armenia U21
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Austria U21
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Estonia U21
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Ecuador
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Peru
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentA: Baderan Tehran
2021-06-08 11:01:51,650 WARN o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: opponentB: Esteghlal Mollasani
```

When I try to assign value so I can use multiple dynamic variables, as

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    vars.put("opponentA" + (i + 1), vars.get("ID1_" + i).split(" - ")[0]);
    vars.put("opponentB" + (i + 1), vars.get("ID1_" + i).split(" - ")[1]);

    log.warn(vars.get("opponentA1"));
    log.warn(vars.get("opponentB1"));
}
```

I got `null`.

How to fix this, so I can use multiple dynamic variables as:

```
opponentA1, opponentA2...opponentA20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
vars.put("opponentA" + (i + 1)...
```

to this:

```
vars.put("opponentA" + i...
```

as your loop starts with 1 so then you increment the value by 1 you're getting variables like `opponentA2`, `opponentB2`, `opponentA3`, etc.

You can always check which variables are being generated using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

It also worth checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries indicating your JSR223 PostProcessor's failure

Comment: yap, the honey for me was: vars.put("opponentA" + i, (vars.get("ID1_" + i)).split(" - ")[0]);